# Why are the Frost Giants in 'Thor' so short?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, thor-2011

The Giants of Jotunheim are enormous superhuman beings, most of whom dwell in the other dimensional realm of Jotunheim, one of the Nine Worlds of Asgardian cosmology. They are the traditional enemies of the gods of Asgard, with whom they have gone to war numerous times over the millennia.

The Giants are basically humanoid in appearance with their most distinguishing feature being their height. Per mythology and Marvel Universe Wiki, the average Frost Giant is twenty feet tall, although some reach up to thirty feet. Why then did they get shrunk down to about 8-10' tall during the movie?

More on Marvel.com: http://marvel.com/universe/Giants_of_Jotunheim#ixzz2zTY50uaZ

[image]

Comment: Just speculating, but probably to make it more believable that Tom Hiddleston could have been a "runt" even though he's at least 6 feet tall.

Comment: Maybe to prevent speculation on how a 30 foot giant king and a 6 foot goddess managed to , ahem, "get it on" to produce Loki...

Comment: @WOPR - There is no mention in Marvel or mythology of Loki being half-asgardian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely answer is that there is too much of a size difference between 'real' Frost Giants and Asgardians to support the story line. It's difficult to stage a believable battle or one-on-one confrontation when the heroes can only reach to their opponent's knees.

Not only would the 20-30' tall Frost Giants look too formidable to be beaten by such tiny opposition, it would be too unwieldy to get both Frost Giants and Asgardians on the screen at the same time. All the Frost Giants would be at least as large as the Destroyer and some much larger.

In effect, the major theme and flow of the storyline would have been overshadowed by the sheer size of the Frost giants. Imagine a 30' tall Laufey crawling through Odin's bedchamber door on his hands and knees after he and another 25' tall giant 'sneak' through the heart of Asgard. Just doesn't work.

Comment: True, why that would be like dwarves and hobbits taking on a dragon!

Comment: @JohnP: more like dwarves and hobbits taking on an army of dragons who invade Hobbiton.

Comment: You've obviously never played Lord of the Rings: Conquest ;) the poor hobbits have to battle a bloody Balrog!